# How to get body text of webpage with all attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to extract dynamic content from page, with exactly same as it is in webpage not plain text.
I am using below block which gives the plain text but i need like attribted text.

```
function getDocumentTranslatedText() {
    return document.body.innerText;    
}
```

Any suggestion would be more helpful.

Comment: if you want tags too, use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead of `innerText`

Comment: If you're trying to get RTF then you're out of luck.  It's plain text or HTML.

Comment: @Archer i am looking for RTF .

Comment: Then you have your answer.  You'll need software to convert HTML to RTF.  You're not doing it in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to get a HTML string rather than a plain text string that you'd get from [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerText).

```
return document.body.innerHTML;
```